# PHP: Transformación de web estructurada a POO + MVC

Tags: php, mvc, poo, controller

Estoy "traduciendo" una página que ya casi tenía hecha de forma estructurada a POO + MVC. Lo estoy haciendo siguiendo las indicaciones de un curso de Udemy, y el instructor utiliza un controlador frontal en el index que decide vía GET a qué controlador y a qué método de dicho controlador se está llamando; algo similar a esto:

```
if($_GET["controlador"]) $controlador_c = $_GET["controlador"]."C";
else $controlador_c = controlador_base;

$controlador = new $controlador_c;

if($_GET["accion"])
{
    $accion = $GET["accion"];
    $controlador->$accion();
}
else
{
    $accion = accion_base;
    $controlador->$accion();
}
```

Mi web original tiene un "controlador" frontal que carga documentos enteros en los que se mezclan llamadas a la base de datos, lógica diversa, HTML, etc., tal que así:

```
if($_GET['fichero']) $archivo = $_GET['fichero'];
else $archivo = 'global.php';

include($archivo);
```

Mi duda es cómo adaptar mi web al nuevo sistema, porque para replicar algunos documentos creo que voy a tener que cargar en ocasiones varios objetos distintos creados a partir del mismo controlador, o de distintos controladores incluso, y me surge la duda de cómo llamarlos a todos a la vez.

Por ejemplo, el documento "decadas.php":

[image: Décadas]

En éste se hacen dos llamadas a la base de datos muy similares, lo que pasa que la de la columna izquierda está limitada a 15 resultados y la de la derecha, a 3.

Esto, en POO, supongo que implicaría crear dos objetos con distintos parámetros a partir del mismo controlador, pero ¿a cuál llamar mediante el controlador frontal? ¿Y cómo mostrar ambos a continuación?

Un saludo y gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno puedes crearlo de muchas formas, una forma de abanzar podría ser pasando como argumento la accion que quieres realizar al metodo accion, y dentro hacer todas las llamadas que necesites.

Tal que así

```
$controlador->accion($_GET['accion'])

class controlador {

    function accion($accion){
        switch($accion){
            case 'total':
              $this->Lista1 = this->cargarLista1();
              $this->Lista2 = this->cargarLista2();
              break:
            case 'lista1':
              $this->Lista1 = this->cargarLista1();
              break;
            case 'lista2':
              $this->Lista2 = this->cargarLista2();
              break;
            default :
              break;
        }
    }
}
```

También seria buena idea en vez de cargar varias listas de lo que necesites construir un objeto respuesta para devolverlo.

Buena suerte!